# txt file to save the link to your phone

Tags: android

I have a link to the txt file. I want by pressing the button to save it to your phone. but I did not get. help please!

```
  void writeFile() throws IOException {
        File myFile = new File("/sdcard/mysdfile.txt");
        myFile.createNewFile();
        HttpURLConnection httpURLConnection = null;
        assert httpURLConnection != null;
        FileOutputStream fOut = new FileOutputStream(myFile);
        OutputStreamWriter myOutWriter = new OutputStreamWriter(fOut);
        myOutWriter.append("my text");
        myOutWriter.close();
        fOut.close();
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Done writing SD 'mysdfile.txt'", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
```

only instead of "my text" I need "%D0%96%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%BD%D1%8C%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE_%D0%B4%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B2%D1%86%D0%B0.*%D0%A0%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%B7%D1%8B.txt">http://www.e-reading.bz/txt.php/1002963/%D0%9C%D0%B8%D1%88%D0%B8%D0%BD*-_%D0%96%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%BD%D1%8C_%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%BE%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE_%D0%B4%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B2%D1%86%D0%B0._%D0%A0%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%B7%D1%8B.txt"

Comment: You might want to read this, which is a really helpful tutorial made by Google about data storage:
http://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/files.html Enjoy ;)

Answer (score 0):

My solution worked

```
 URL url = new URL(my link); //you can write here any link
        URLConnection ucon = url.openConnection();
        InputStream is = ucon.getInputStream();
        BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(is);
        ByteArrayBuffer baf = new ByteArrayBuffer(5000);
        int current = 0;
        while ((current = bis.read()) != -1) {
            baf.append((byte) current);
        }
        FileOutputStream fos = new FileOutputStream("/sdcard/mysdfile.txt");
        fos.write(baf.toByteArray());
        fos.flush();
        fos.close();
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Done writing SD 'mysdfile.txt'", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();






<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE"></uses-permission>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"></uses-permission>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE"></uses-permission>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"></uses-permission>
```